# How to best transport bulots - sea snails aka welks?

Tags: food-preservation, seafood, snail

I've just bought 2 kg bulots in France and would like to drive them home over 1000 km.

What's the best option to preserve them?

- freeze
- keep in cool* water (car has an electric but weak coolbox)
- cook first and transport cooked

- fresh or salted like their home environment?

Comment: why are you asking about "like their home environment", are they alive?

Comment: @rumtscho probably alive if he ask to cook them before transport ?